# Copy special charecters e.g. urdu letters from one database to other database

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to copy the data from one database to another.

In db1, there is column which has following values:

```
|        19 | ٢       |
|        19 | ٣       |
|        19 | ٤       |
+----------------+---------+
```

Charset of both db1 table and db2 table are the same:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

When i try to copy them, then its storing as '?' marks.

INSERT STATEMENT using Perl:

```
$dbh2->do( 'SET NAMES utf8;');
$dbh2->do( 'SET COLLATION utf8_general_ci;');

$select = $dbh1->prepare("SELECT * FROM db1");
$insert = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO db2 VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$select->execute;
while ( my($WORD,$SENSITIVE,$REGEXP) = $select->fetchrow_array )
{
  $insert->execute($WORD,$SENSITIVE,$REGEXP,'NULL');
}
```

WORD is the column, which has urdu characters.

Comment: set `Collation` to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: but how come its stored properly in db1 where collation is COLLATE=utf8_bin;

Comment: @ashu : check as Pathik suggested as this may be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

These characters cannot be seen in pure ASCII. MySQL instance is not configured to expect UTF-8 encoding by default from client connections.

Run the following query before insert operation:

SET NAMES utf8;

For more info about connection character set you can see [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html).

Comment: i tried, still the same case, when i export the db to sql file which has urdu characters, i see value ''Ù¡' in this pattern .

Comment: Good, at least it's not ? anymore :D Now try this one also SET CHARACTER SET cp1250; some clients doesn't understand the utf-8

Comment: Remember it is not just the database. You should set the charset everywhere, (perl and html), in you application when you're dealing with special characters. Check this article: https://perlgeek.de/en/article/encodings-and-unicode